# How can I get Outlook to remind me twice for a given appointment?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

Is there any way I can get outlook to remind me X minutes prior to every meeting request, and once right when the meeting/appointment happens.

Answer (score 1):

According to  [Microsoft](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/outlook-multiple-reminders-set/fc8ae720-6fc5-49a8-a893-4f50dc3e06fd) this can't be done. You can, however, snooze a reminder should you wish for another a set period of time later. Think this is the best you are going to get.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your reminder (for say an hour ahead of time), and then choose to snooze until 5 minutes before.  It's not exactly two reminders, but works that way in practice.